# multidimensional cell array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, cell, cells

I'v 3 *cell arrays* of same number of cells, However I want to reduce in only one *cell array* having multiple dimensions so that they can be access by column wise like array's column. I'm working in *Matlab's* environment, However I'v tried to do so, but unfortunately I'v  found no cell access as column as in matrices. Any Suggestions for handle such case?

**My Code:**

```
    P = cell(1,10);
    Pd = cell(1,10);
Pdd = cell(1,10);
    for ii=1:10
        P{ii}= [repmat([0 0 0],2,1)];
        Pd{ii} = [repmat([1 1 1],2,1)];
Pdd{ii} = [repmat([2 2 2],2,1)];
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the three cell arrays vertically:

```
Pall = [P; Pd; Pdd]
```

This gives a 3x10 cell array `Pall`, such that `Pall(1,:)`  is `P`, etc.

If you want to avoid creating multiple cell arrays from the beginning: do something similar to this:

```
for ii=1:10
   Pall{1,ii}= [repmat([0 0 0],2,1)];
   Pall{2,ii} = [repmat([1 1 1],2,1)];
   Pall{3,ii} = [repmat([2 2 2],2,1)];
end
```

To avoid loops, with the values in your example:

```
Pall = mat2cell(repmat([repmat([0 0 0],2,1); repmat([1 1 1],2,1); repmat([2 2 2],2,1)],1,10),[2 2 2],3*ones(1,10))
```

Comment: I want to avoid creating multiple cell arrays, `cellfun(@(x) [1 0 0], num2cell(1:2)', 'UniformOutput', false)` this can't be use instead?

Comment: I want to reduce statements and strongly avoid the looping.

Comment: @AhsanAli: Did Luis Mendo help you?

Comment: Not that solution which I want, anyother solution may help for me instead.

Comment: *any other solution may help me instead* - that's a pretty bold attitude coming from someone who clearly has no idea what they're asking in a good majority of posts here on SO. What specifically is wrong with the last solution?

Comment: @Daniel Thank you too for caring :-)